# Word for a person who is asking someone to be his friend

Tags: terminology

Whats the correct term for someone who's asking other to be his friend? "Requester" works? And what about the person who will respond to this request? How can I refer to them?

Comment: Is the context from FB or something similar?

Comment: Yes, I'm creating a database (for friendships) and I need the user who sent the request and the one that received it

Comment: Ah...unfortunately "...Naming, including naming programming variables/classes...is considered off-topic" That said, you might get some advice in comment. Since _friend_ is already being used as a verb in this type of context, how about "friender" and "friendee"?

Comment: @Cascabel: Actually, the derived form [***befriendee***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22befriendee%22) already has some currency. And per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=26&smoothing=3&content=befriendee%2Cfriendee&year_end=2019&year_start=1800&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbefriendee%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfriendee%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cbefriendee%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfriendee%3B%2Cc0), it seems that ***friendee*** was around a couple of centuries ago, but has been almost completely displaced by the longer version in recent decades.